# Can't install appcelerator ti.storekit module

Tags: appcelerator

I am trying to install the ti.storekit module from [GitHub](https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.storekit) but having a hard time.  On that page, I click the Clone or Download button, then Download the zip file.  I then go into Appcelerator Studio and click Help/Install Mobile Module.  I then select the zip file I downloaded.  I want to use it in more than one app, so I select "Titanium SDK".  After clicking OK, it says it installed ok, but I cannot add the module in tiapp.xml - it doesn't show as a choice.  If I try to install just to 1 project, I get the same results.

After installing, it puts a ti.storekit-master folder into ~/Library/Application Support/Titanium (not into the modules folder), which seems odd.  When trying to install to 1 project, it puts ti.storekit-master folder in the root of my project, which doesn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Appcelerator Studio: build 4.7.1.201609100950

ios SDK: 5.5.1.GA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you clone / download from the repo you are downloading the source code -- you don't need to do this unless you want to build it from source.

Download from https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.storekit/releases the latest release you want -- you can simply copy this to the root of your project and build and it'll be unzipped automatically into the modules folder -- or just install from appc studio.

Answer (score 1):

jasonkneen had the solution, download the release zip, not the source zip, from github.